# Flyway docker will auto restart after finishing migrate by docker compose commit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, flyway

This is my first time using Flyway for Database migration. And it's a great tool for solving my problem of keeping the whole team using the same database and example data.

But there is a small problem. I use Docker to set up my environment for Database (Mariadb), phpMyAdmin, and Flyway(Community Version). I think I didn't miss any setting up for my `docker-compose.yml`, but sometimes my migration will not startup, and every time my flyway finish migrating. My flyway container will `exit 1` start restarting.

What I hope is my flyway container will not close after finishing migration. But I find out that flyway will close the container after finishing migration. So if the container is down for sure. Is there any way to stop restarting it?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
    mariadb:
      image: mariadb:10.10.2
      container_name: db
      hostname: mariadb
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./database/backup:/backup
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      # settings timezone for database
      command: --default-time-zone '+00:00'
      ports:
        - ${SQL_FORWARD_PORT}:3306
      healthcheck:
        test: "mysql -hlocalhost -u$DB_USERNAME -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_DATABASE -e 'select 1'"
        interval: 1s
        timeout: 3s
        retries: 30
      platform: linux/amd64
  
    pma:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.2.0
      container_name: pma
      hostname: pma
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mariadb
      ports:
        - ${PMA_FORWARD_PORT}:80
      depends_on:
        mariadb: 
          condition: service_healthy
      platform: linux/amd64

    flyway:
      # use flyway Community edition docker
      image: flyway/flyway:9.16.1
      # use flyway Teams and Enterprise edition docker
      # image: redgate/flyway-teams:9.16.1
      container_name: flyway
      hostname: flyway
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - ./flyway/sql:/flyway/sql
        - ./flyway/conf:/flyway/conf
        - ./flyway/drivers:/flyway/drivers
      command: migrate
      depends_on:
        mariadb: 
          condition: service_healthy
      platform: linux/amd64
```

and my directory structure as below
[project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEf9Z.png)

The migrate finish without any error, so I do not show my *.sql file. If need please let me know.

Hope anyone can help me QQ.

I used the wrong Docker image at first and thought the problem is the license. But changing the image didn't fix the problem.
My migration naming is `V**.***__xxx`, which `**` stands for `01 ~ 99` and `***` stands for `001 ~ 999`. Since Migrate has been correctly implemented. The naming of the file maybe is not the problem that restarts my container.

Comment: You explicitly have a `restart:` policy set for the migration container; do you need to change that?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the answer. Yes, the restart is because of my docker-compose setup. But I have a new problem. Can I stop flyway from closing itself ?

Comment: Why would you?  The migrations are done; what is there to keep alive?

Comment: @DavidMaze Sometimes migration is not finish properly. And when i'm trying to get into flyway container to find out the reason and clean my database. The container just keeps closing. I'm not able to give any command. So I hope there is any way for me to hold it.